# How to show javafx context menu without show window

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

In my case, someone will call a method with a screen point. I want to show a javafx context menu on the point without showing any window(even it must be created).

Answer (score 1):

You can make your owning window transparent and it won't be seen, only the context menu you require will be displayed.  Note, show still need to be called on the owning window, even though the window cannot be seen, as the ContextMenu implementation requires an owning window in order to function.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class OutOfContext extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ContextMenu contextMenu = createContextMenu();

        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(), 0, 0, Color.TRANSPARENT));
        showContextMenu(contextMenu, stage, 150, 100);
    }

    private void showContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, Stage owner, double x, double y) {
        owner.setX(x);
        owner.setY(y);
        owner.show();

        contextMenu.setX(x);
        contextMenu.setY(y);
        contextMenu.show(owner);
    }

    private ContextMenu createContextMenu() {
        MenuItem game = new MenuItem("Global Thermonuclear War");
        game.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println("This is not a good option.");
            Platform.exit();
        });

        MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit");
        exit.setOnAction(event -> Platform.exit());

        return new ContextMenu(
                game,
                exit
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I init the stage with `StageStyle.UTILITY` and set x by `Double.MAX_VALUE`. It seems like just a context menu without window.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example on how to create a `ContextMenu` for a specific node of your scene

```
final ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem cmItem1 = new MenuItem("Copy Image");
cmItem1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
         // do something
    }
});

// add the menu item to the menu
cm.getItems().add(cmItem1);

// bind the menu to a node of you scene e.g. canvas
node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
              cm.show(pic, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
        }
});

// display the ContextMenu at specific location
cm.show(anchor, screenX, screenY);
```

Comment: I have no node, no scene, no window. Just need a context menu.

Comment: If you have no node, no scene and no windows than a ContextMenu is not possible, in JavaFX you can only create ContextMenus for nodes, scenes or windows

Comment: Yes, you are right. But can I create window and hide it, only show context menu associate with it.